# Next JS module ferderation

Tags: next.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to create micro-frontend with NextJS, for that I am using `@module-federation/nextjs-mf` npm package. I have created 2 seperate nextJS projects with Next CLI inside a parent folder. The 2 projects are namely **home** and **reactcomponents** and I am trying to share a component from later to the former.

The `nextjs.config.js` for **reactcomponents** looks like below,

```
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: 'components',
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            "./Button": "./components/Button.jsx",
            "./MovieCard": "./components/MovieCard.jsx"
          },
        }),
      );
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

and for the **home** component it is like,

```
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: 'home',
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
          remotes: {
            components: "components@http//localhost:3001/.next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js"
          }
        }),
      );
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

When I run these applications I get below error on Browser for **home**

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/MovieCard'`

and, the below error on Visual studio terminal,

```
No ModuleFederationPlugin(s) found.
error - ./pages/index.js:3:35
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/MovieCard'
```

You can find the code at [Github](https://github.com/tripaider/next-mf)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes here:

- You are using a wrong endpoint path for your remote it should be:

```js
remotes: {
  components: 'components@http://localhost:3001/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
},
```

- You need to apply NextFederationPlugin without a condition
- Whenever you're using module federation with Next.js we recommend you to use [next/dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) instead of React.lazy

I made a [PR](https://github.com/tripaider/next-mf/pull/1) fixing the inconsistencies, I'd highly recommend for you to take a look at the [module-federation-examples](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/) as there are a lot of examples that can help you

Comment: Now I have created another micro frontend named 'navigation', which renders a list navigation link on its / route after making a API call. Now when I expose this route as a component with './PrimaryNavigation': './pages/indrx.js' in next.config.js and try to consume in my home app, I get error "TypeError: fn is not a function while loading './PrimaryNavigation' from Webpack/container/reference/navigation".

Comment: I tried to refer Webpack documentation, it says, "you are likely missing the remote container" - but it does not making any sense to me.

Comment: I also tried implementing Promise Based Dynamic Remotes, but that made me more confused. I am getting ReferenceError: window is not defined.